# Is there a way to connect to a soap webservice without using a web reference in C#?

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0

is there some library out there that will accept the url of the soap wsdl file, and then generate me the proxy classes and what not at runtime? Web references are getting to be somewhat inconvenient for my particular situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Web Services Description Language Tool (Wsdl.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.71%29.aspx) is what you want.

The following command creates a client proxy class in the C# language for an XML Web service located at the specified URL. The tool saves the client proxy class in the file myProxyClass.cs.

```
wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs http://hostServer/WebserviceRoot/WebServiceName.asmx?WSDL
```

Comment: I'm assuming that somehow I'll be able to use this .cs file using reflection somehow right? I need to create the file and use it in the same program instance.

Comment: So what you want is Creating the SOAP Envelope through generated WSDL and send your messages by filling it with your data? Maybe this helps http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d2207785-56ee-41e3-a2ee-71b024ca8864/

Comment: Reading this article also may enlighten us. esp the Proxy API section http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/NET-WCF-vs-Java-JAX-WS-and-JAX-RS.aspx

Comment: Ah sorry, circumstances have changed now.. I don't need to do this anymore. I'll be unable to eventually accept your answer.